# Create an SQL database (.mdf) using mysql workbench?

Tags: .net, database, c#-4.0, mysql-workbench

I have installed the mysql products for developers and have proceeded to 'create a schema' which according to other blogs and forums is mysql language to create a database. After that, I tried importing that database file into my C# project which is what I do with my Access databases but I can't seem to find the database? Also, I can't find any function on the mysql workbench to create or export the database I have created. It is complete with tables around 10 tables, and an unfinished diagram. I want to import the database for publising of the C # application.

Comment: Try reading this article: http://www.mkyong.com/mysql/where-does-mysql-stored-the-data-in-my-harddisk/

Comment: it does not help.. the my.ini file is not in the mysql folder specified in the article

Comment: i found the my.ini file in another folder. but the supposed to be .mdf database file of the database I created using workbench is not there. it seems that it is only a collection of .frm files.

Comment: Well, those file ARE the MySQL database. The .mdf file is the extension used by SQL Server

Comment: Are MySQL instances different from SQL Server instances? I also can't seem to find the two servers I made using MySQL workbench on Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio which I installed just now.